# Access elements in summary() in R

Tags: r, statistics, output, element

I would like to access some elements of an Anova summary in R. I've been trying things like in this question [Access or parse elements in summary() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25225480/3801533).

When I convert the summary to a string it shows something like this:

```
str(summ)
List of 1
 $ :Classes 'anova' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Df     : num [1:2] 3 60
  ..$ Sum Sq : num [1:2] 0.457 2.647
  ..$ Mean Sq: num [1:2] 0.1523 0.0441
  ..$ F value: num [1:2] 3.45 NA
  ..$ Pr(>F) : num [1:2] 0.022 NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "summary.aov" "listof"
```

How can I access the F value?
I've been trying things like `summ[c('F value')]` and I still can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `summ[[1]]$\`F value\`` will work

Comment: summ[[1]]["F value"][[1]][1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the anova object inside a list (first line of str output is List of 1). So you need to get the "F value" of this single element, like:

```
 summm[[1]][["F value"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the answer above I'd recommend to start using the `broom` package when you want to access/use various elements of a model object.

First, by using the `str` command you don't convert the summary into a string, but you just see the structure of your summary, which is a list. So, `str` means "structure".

The `broom` package enables you to save the info of your model object as a data frame, which is easier to manipulate. Check my simple example:

```
library(broom)

fit <- aov(mpg ~ vs, data = mtcars)

# check the summary of the ANOVA (not possible to access info/elements)
fit2 = summary(fit)

fit2

#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
# vs           1  496.5   496.5   23.66 3.42e-05 ***
# Residuals   30  629.5    21.0 


# create a data frame of the ANOVA
fit3 = tidy(fit)

fit3

#        term df    sumsq    meansq statistic      p.value
# 1        vs  1 496.5279 496.52790  23.66224 3.415937e-05
# 2 Residuals 30 629.5193  20.98398        NA           NA


# get F value (or any other values)
fit3$statistic[1]

#[1] 23.66224
```

I think for the specific example you provided you don't really need to use the `broom` method, but if it happens to deal with more complicated model objects it will be really useful to try it.